# extract Geo location of Tweet

Tags: geolocation, tweepy, sentiment-analysis, tweetstream

Is there any way we culd extract Geo location of tweet, even when user did not enable the location?
I am looking to collect tweets from  specific states for sentiment analysis of tweets.
Please help

class StdOutListener(StreamListener): #class allow us to print tweets
def on_data(self, data):
full_tweet = json.loads(data)
##this makes sure that you won't get clipped tweets
if 'extended_tweet' in full_tweet:
tweet_text = full_tweet.get('full_text')
else:
tweet_text = full_tweet.get('text')
tweet_time = full_tweet.get('created_at')
tweet_lang = full_tweet.get('lang')
if tweet_lang != None and tweet_lang == 'en' and tweet_text != None and 'RT @' not in tweet_text:
##this is only taking the text and the time stamp, which is making the DB very space effecient
tweetObject = {
"text": tweet_text,
"time": tweet_time,
}
scPrimary.insert_one(tweetObject)
return True

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible unless the user has enabled the feature (it is off by default), more [here](https://help.twitter.com/en/safety-and-security/tweet-location-settings)

If the feature is enabled then when retrieving a tweet (with any of the available methods) you can get this information in the Status object (model returned by Tweepy API methods):

```
status.coordinates # ie [-49.319543, -16.679431]
status.place.full_name # ie The Netherlands
status.user.location
```